# Q: TYPO3 - RTE doesn't contain 'insert image' button

Tags: image, typo3

Hello stackoverflow friends,

i have a problem, i'm new to typo3 and want to create some text with image. i try it for some time now but i dont get it. I don't have an insert image button in my text editor. installed several extensions, CKEditor and stuff.

Here is an image of my symbols:
[image]

We tried "text & media" and "text and pictures". There is just no button for inserting an image.

Yours sincerely or so

Comment: @EdChum It's a common problem configuring the Editor in TYPO3, especially related to the image-functionality which combines functions of CKEditor and TYPO3. IMHO this item is not off-topic and should be opened again (even an answer exists already).

Answer (score 3):

"Text and Images" and "Text and Media" content elements don't add images to the CKEditor text; you add them with the "Images" tab and they are not "embedded" in the text written with CKEditor. They are written in the HTML wrapped with the markup necessary to create a grid of images with multiple rows/columns.

In the "Gallery Settings" box inside the same tab you can decide the position of the images with respect to the text.

If you want to add support for the images *inside* the CKEditor, you have to install the extension https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/rte_ckeditor_image/

You can find here some articles about how to customize the configuration of CKEditor on TYPO3:

https://typo3worx.eu/2017/02/configure-ckeditor-in-typo3/

https://usetypo3.com/ckeditor.html